# Externals with webpack and electron

Tags: webpack, electron

I’m using React with Webpack and Electron and I’m trying to require the remote from the renderer process. My code is being transpired by Babel + Webpack but this line of code:

```
import {remote} from 'electron'
```

is giving me

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "electron"
```

How can I fix this? I know that the issue is because electron injects the electron module on the rendering of the page which webpack doesn’t know about it.

```
const {remote} = window.require('electron')
```

Works fine because it’s ignored by webpack.

Comment: Try and use electron instead of electron-prebuilt.. The latest versions of electron are released as electron..

Comment: @shashi Ok I’ll try that

Comment: Still not working @shashi

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of webpack, set the target property to `electron-renderer` in the renderer configuration.

```
module.exports = {
 target: 'electron-renderer',
 //... other configurations
}
```

If you are using webpack to bundle main(main.js), set the target property to `electron-main` in the main configuration.

```
module.exports = {
 target: 'electron-main',
 //... other configurations
}
```